# Slicing on Pandas Series Object with Index List Having Multiple Datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I just started learning Pandas and I don't understand how slicing works when the index list contains objects of multiple types.

```
import pandas as pd
arr = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index = [2, 3, 'six', 'eight'])
arr[2:3] #Output -- 30
arr[3:'six'] #TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [3] of <class 'int'>
arr['six':'eight'] #Output -- 30, 40
```

Isn't arr[2:3] supposed to be 20  and isn't arr['six':'eight'] supposed to be just 30?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.02-data-indexing-and-selection.html).

Answer (score 2):

Pandas working best if not mixed types of values in index.

Working general solution here is get positions for each index by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and select by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
arr = pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index = [2, 3, 'six', 'eight'])

print (arr.iloc[arr.index.get_loc(2):arr.index.get_loc(3)])
2    10
dtype: int64

print (arr.iloc[arr.index.get_loc(3):arr.index.get_loc('six')])
3    20
dtype: int64

print (arr.iloc[arr.index.get_loc('six'):arr.index.get_loc('eight')])
six    30
dtype: int64
```

Your solution partly working:

First if select by both integers, pandas indexing like by positions (like with `iloc`):

```
print (arr[2:3])
six    30
dtype: int64

print (arr.iloc[2:3])
six    30
dtype: int64
```

And if select by both labels, pandas select like by labels (like with `loc`):

```
print (arr['six':'eight'])
six      30
eight    40
dtype: int64

print (arr.loc['six':'eight'])
six      30
eight    40
dtype: int64
```

Selecting by mixed values is not implemented, so raised error - pandas try select by labels (like with `loc`), but found integer (what is used for select by positions).